# Right way to connect Angular to Elasticsearch

Tags: angular, express, elasticsearch

It seems I've misunderstood how to integrate Elasticsearch within the MEAN stack 2.0 (Angular). I'm using Elasticsearch for search and autocomplete in my movie app.

I've BEEN connecting Angular directly to my ES server and after much frustration and lots of reading... it seems that I should actually:
1. Connect my Angular Component to
2. My Angular Search Service to
3. My Express api route which
4. Finally connects to my ES Server.

So my Angular Search Service should NOT connect directly to my ES Server.  While I know its possible to connect Angular directly to ES, lots of recommendations against for security purposes.

It seems basically that I should import a search service into my Angular components for search and autocomplete. That Angular service should call an Express API route and that Express API should connect to the ES Server. Express should act as the middleman between Angular and Elasticsearch. Angular should never communicate directly with the ES Server.

Do I understand correctly now?

Comment: Please include more details to the question. What data are you going to show from Elastic Search?. Are you trying to use https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js ?

Comment: For Angular app it doesn't really matter if you're using ES directly or through Express. Both expose REST API that can be requested with Angular HttpClient. The only difference is that you can't use official ES client in the second case. *Do I understand correctly now?* - yes. Case closed?

Comment: You can check with my project here https://github.com/JinnaBalu/elasticangular as there is no big story as expected.